# Uniform convergence, and how to show it?

Tags: uniform-convergence

We've just been introduced to uniform convergence, and the method presented is to take the supremum of the absolute value of the difference between the limit function and the function in the sequence, and show that this is less than $\epsilon$ for $n \ge N$ regardless of $x$.

I think I may have misunderstood something, for I am looking at a problem, and i don't know how to apply above? Essentially, we have a sequence of functions $\frac{1-(x/4)^n}{1+(2/x)^n}$ for $x \in (2,4)$: show uniform convergence towards $1$.... but that function does go towards 1, for all x, as $x/4 < 1$and $2/x< 1$? So is this pointwise convergence I've shown, or is it also uniform?

Comment: Observe that **for any** $\;x\in (2,4)\;,\;\;\dfrac{1-(x/4)^n}{1+(2/x)^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\dfrac{1-0}{1+0}=1\;$

Comment: Yes, exactly. So is this uniform convergence, or pointwise? I am looking up definitions on wikipedia, the one with logical symbols, and they seem so alike to me that I cna't spot the difference.

Comment: It is *uniform* since the above happens **for any** $\;x\in (2,4)\;$ ...! Of course, this is also pointwise, and a little more could be done to make the argument completely formal.

Comment: @Timbuc what you have shown is pointwise convergence not uniform convergence.......because convergence happening for every $x$ does not mean uniform convergence

Comment: @UrbanPENDU I don't think **though** something more is needed to make the argument formal, say: $\;\sup\left|f_n(x)-1\right|\longrightarrow 0\;$ , with $\;f_n\;$ our function...but this is already and easier taks, imo.

Comment: @Timbuc Your last comment is fine....but I don't see $\sup$ coming in your first comment.....and as an example in support of my previous comment....consider the sequence $f_n(x) = x^n$.....thought it converges for every $x$ but yet the convergence is not uniform.....

Comment: @UrbanPENDU No, and neither you'll see it in my answer. This is left to the OP in case that's the way (s)he wants to do it/they defined that in class.

Answer (score 1):

Formally:

$$\left|\frac{1-\left(\frac x4\right)^n}{1+\left(\frac2x\right)^n}-1\right|=\frac{\left(\frac2x\right)^n+\left(\frac x4\right)^n}{1+\left(\frac2x\right)^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

and the above doesn't depend on a specific $\;x\in(2,4)\;$

More formally: you want to show that for any $\;\epsilon >0\;$ there exists $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ s.t.

$$n>N\implies |f_n(x)-1|<\epsilon\;,\;\;\text{for any}\;\;x\in (2,4)$$

Well, use the first part and the fact that the num erator on the right side of the equality converges to zero whether the denominator approaches $\;1\;$

Answer (score 0):

The convergence is not uniform on $(2,4).$ Let $$(1)\,\,\,\,f_n(x) = \frac{1-(x/4)^n}{1+(2/x)^n}.$$ We know $f_n(x) \to 1$ pointwise on $(2,4).$ Suppose the convergence is uniform. Crucial fact: Then for any sequence $x_n$ in $(2,4),$ we have $f(x_n) \to 1.$* Plugging $x_n = 4-1/n$ into (1), the numerators then equal $1-(1-(1/4n))^n \to 1-e^{-1/4}.$ The denominators $\to 1.$ Thus $f_n(4-1/n)\to 1- e^{-1/4}\ne 1$ contradiction.

*Suppose $f_n \to f$ uniformly on some set $E.$ Then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup_{E}|f_n-f| = 0.$ Let $x_n$ be any sequence in $E.$ Then $$|f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| \le \sup_{E}|f_n-f|\to 0.$$

Comment: I think you might be right (and then I might wrong) and the convergence isn't uniform, yet the reason you give is giving me problems: shouldn't it be that the sequence *must converge* (in the given interval)? Anyway, could you please direct me to a source for this?

Comment: Hi, I added a little bit more in my answer to cover your question (which is a good one).